# Evento Boton Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

alguien me podría ayudar para la inserción de un evento clic y pueda darme acceso a otra ventana donde guarde dicha variable.
despues de ejecutar el codigo se abre la ventana donde se escribe el usuario, se da aceptar abre el jfilechooser para cargar archivos, pero en la consola me da un error.

¿donde sería más apropiado poner el evento de clic?
agradezco si alguien me podría orientar :d

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DemoJFileChooser panel = new DemoJFileChooser();

    JPanel user = new JPanel();
    frame.add(user);
    placeComponents(user);
    frame.setVisible(true); 

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
    frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}   
private static void placeComponents(JPanel user){

    user.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Usuario");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    user.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    user.add(userText);
}   

public class DemoJFileChooser extends JPanel
   implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel user = new JPanel();

    JLabel message = new JLabel("");
    JButton go;

    JFileChooser chooser;
    String choosertitle;

  public DemoJFileChooser() {
    go = new JButton("INGRESAR");
    go.addActionListener(this);
    add(user);
    add(go);
    add(message);
  }
```

En el segundo codigo guarde el nombre que ingrese el usuario

```
public class App extends Window {
private static String path; 
public static void daemon() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Conecting to server ....");
    RSync rsync = new RSync();
    //VARIABLE QUE SE GUARDA DESDE EL OTRO CODIGO
    String variable="";
    rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-avz","-e","ssh",path,variable+"@192.168.2.219:rsync"});
    ConsoleOutputProcessOutput output = new ConsoleOutputProcessOutput();
    output.monitor(rsync.builder());
}
```